# Работа с bitmap. Размещение элементов в определенном месте

Tags: android, bitmap

**Дано:**

Картинка .jpg определенным размером, с соотношением 1:10 (ширина:высота).

**Что хочу получить:**

- Большая картинка должна скролиться от начала до конца.
- В **определенных** местах на большой картинке должны быть разные
  элементы, такие как: другая картинка(которая двигается туда-сюда
  анимацией), поле для ввода, viewPager.

**Вопрос:**

Как в определенном месте картинки показывать определенный элемент ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для загрузки картинки большого размера ее нужно уменьшать(scale) и тогда загружать в ImageView.

В данном случае картинка была очень большого размера(более 8000 в высоту) и ее порезал на определенные части и их уже в ImageView загружал.

Что касается размещения элементов поверх картинки:
нужно использовать в разметке RelativeLayout, в нем размещать ImageView и предварительно высчитав положение необходимого View - задавать этому View значения(marginTop, marginLeft).

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо в момент исполнения программы получить размеры и координаты картинки на экране. После этого, зная (заранее примерив на макете и измерив) где должны быть остальные элементы вам надо их программно расположить относительно картинки.